# js not working in bs3 ajax modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble with *js* inside my *bs3* modals - it does not work.  I am opening the modals with ajax.

**main page**

```
<a href="/modals/comp_activate.php" data-target="#modal-ajax" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Activate this computer</a>';

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-ajax" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <img src="/assets/img/ajax-modal-loading.gif" alt="" class="loading">
</div>

<script src="/assets/scripts/custom/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
        Custom.init();
    });
</script>
```

**custom.js**

```
var Custom = function () {

// private functions & variables

// external window links
var externalWindows = function() {
    $("a[data-window='external']").on('click', function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href')); 
        return false; 
    });
}

// public functions
return {

    //main function
    init: function () {
        //initialize something here
        externalWindows(); // external window links 
    }

};

}();
```

**the link in the modal page**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://www.somesite.com/" data-window="external" onClick="$('#modal-ajax').modal('hide');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Purchase Now</a>
```

All this does is open any link with `data-window="external"` in a new window in the browser.  Since the modal page is opened with ajax the js from the main page doesn't 'pick it up' on load.  I can add the function on my modal page as well, but then it causes issues with the main page.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so that the dynamically loaded links trigger your handler:

```
var externalWindows = function () {
    function openWindow() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href')); 
        return false;
    }

    $("a[data-window='external").click(openWindow);
    $("#modal-ajax").on('click', "a[data-window='external']", openWindow);
};
```

Comment: This worked... I added another function in my custom.js file with ` var externalWindows2 = function() {
  $("#modal-ajax").on('click',"a[data-window='external']", function() {
      window.open($(this).attr('href')); 
      return false; 
  });
 }`  Is this the only way?  This means every js I want to use in the remote modals would need this as well.

Comment: @user756659 no, no need for a second function, just change the one you have for the one I posted, everything should work fine

Comment: Well I need it to work on all pages...not just modals, but 'with' ajax modals.

Comment: Switching out #modal-ajax for body seems to be doing the trick although I would think body would have the same effect as my original?  It is working on both regular pages and modals though.

Comment: @user756659 Yes, typically one uses `document` instead of `body` but what that is doing is attaching the handler to every click on the page and that could end up affecting the performance of your site, it is not the same as your original code because of event propagation, check the link I gave you for reference, also check the reference for jquery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @user756659 you have another couple of options, use the same `externalWindows` function to attach the handler directly to the links and to the modal with delegation or create a handler for the modal show event to attach the handler when the modal is opened

Comment: @user756659 See my edited answer, that's the approach I would take

Comment: Went with one function... one handler for the links and one to the modal with delegation.  Thanks for the help!